# PHP Define var = one or other (aka: $var=($a||$b);)

Tags: php, variables, operators

Is there a way to define a php variable to be one or the other just like you would do `var x = (y||z)` in javascript?

[Get the size of the screen, current web page and browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window/28241682#28241682).

> ```
> var width = window.innerWidth
> || document.documentElement.clientWidth
> || document.body.clientWidth;
>
> var height = window.innerHeight
> || document.documentElement.clientHeight
> || document.body.clientHeight;
> ```

i'm sending a post variable and i want to store it for a later use in a session. What i want to accomplish is to set `$x` to the value of `$_POST['x']`, if any exist, then check and use `$_SESSION['x']` if it exist and leave `$x` undefined if neither of them are set;

```
$x = ($_POST['x'] || $_SESSION['x');
```

According to http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

> $a = 0 || 'avacado'; print "A: $a\n";
>
> will print:
>
> A: 1
>
> in PHP -- as opposed to printing "A: avacado" as it would in a
>   language like Perl or JavaScript.
>
> This means you can't use the '||' operator to set a default value:
>
> $a = $fruit || 'apple';
>
> instead, you have to use the '?:' operator:
>
> $a = ($fruit ? $fruit : 'apple');

so i had to go with an extra if encapsulating the ?: operation like so:

```
if($_POST['x'] || $_SESSION['x']){ 
  $x = ($_POST['x']?$_POST['x']:$_SESSION['x']);
}
```

or the equivalent also working:

```
if($_POST['x']){
  $x=$_POST['x'];
}elseif($_SESSION['x']){
  $x=$_SESSION['x'];
}
```

I didn't test theses but i presume they would work as well:

```
$x = ($_POST['x']?$_POST['x']:
       ($_SESSION['x']?$_SESSION['x']:null)
     );
```

for more variables i would go for a function (not tested):

```
function mvar(){
  foreach(func_get_args() as $v){
    if(isset($v)){
      return $v;
    }
  } return false;
}

$x=mvar($_POST['x'],$_SESSION['x']);
```

Any simple way to achieve the same in php?

EDIT for clarification: in the case we want to use many variables `$x=($a||$b||$c||$d);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I've managed to create a function for you that achieves exactly what you desire, allowing infinite arguements being supplied and fetching as you desire:

```
function _vars() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    // loop through until we find one that isn't empty
    foreach($args as &$item) {
        // if empty
        if(empty($item)) {
            // remove the item from the array
            unset($item);
        } else {
            // return the first found item that exists
            return $item;
        }
    }
    // return false if nothing found    
    return false;
}
```

<sup>*To understand the function above, simply read the comments above.*</sup>

Usage:

```
$a = _vars($_POST['x'], $_SESSION['x']);
```

And here is your:

[**Example**](http://www.tehplayground.com/#aAafD6Flm)

---

It is a very simply ternary operation. You simply need to check the post first and then check the session after:

```
$a = (isset($_POST['x']) && !empty($_POST['x']) ? 
        $_POST['x']
        :
        (isset($_SESSION['x']) && !empty($_SESSION['x']) ? $_SESSION['x'] : null)
    );
```

Comment: `isset($_POST['x']) && !empty($_POST['x'])` can be replaced by ` !empty($_POST['x'])` only i think.

Comment: @b0s3 I was going to doing that originally, but simply thought the OP might want to see a different alternative ;-)

Comment: `empty()` will check for bot if the variable is set and it is empty or not. Also `false` will be treated as empty.

Comment: @Darren thanks, every alternative can be used depending on the needs. ;-) but there's already enough code in your answer for me to build a function

Comment: @LouisLoudogTrottier Updated with a function that achieves what you are looking for.

Comment: Already had the same function in my original question, except for the reference call `&` and the unset(); Since this seems to the the only way, i will accept your updated answer and carry on. Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: @louis i went with `empty` instead of `isset` cause you'd already be passing in the arguments so they'd be set.

Comment: wouldn't this throw a notice with undefined variables?

Comment: @keitha - no, because it only checks items in the array, which are set

Answer (score 2):

Yes you need to use simple `ternary` operator which you have used within your example along with some other functions of PHP like as of `isset` or `empty` functions of PHP. So your variable `$x` will be assigned values respectively

**Example**

```
$x = (!empty($_POST['x'])) ? $_POST['x'] : (!empty($_SESSION['x'])) ? $_SESSION['x'] : NULL;
```

So the above function depicts that if your `$_POST['x']` is set than the value of

```
$x = $_POST['x'];
```

else it'll check for the next value of `$_SESSION` if its set then the value of `$x` will be

```
$x = $_SESSION['x'];
```

else the final value'll be

```
$x = null;// you can set your predefined value instead of null

$x = (!empty($a)) ? $a : (!empty($b)) ? $b : (!empty($c)) ? $c : (!empty($d)) ? $d : null;
```

If you need a function then you can simply achieve it as

```
$a = '';
$b = 'hello';
$c = '';
$d = 'post';

function getX(){
    $args = func_get_args();
    $counter = 1;
    return current(array_filter($args,function($c) use (&$counter){ if(!empty($c) && $counter++ == 1){return $c;} }));
}

$x = getX($a, $b, $c, $d);
echo $x;
```

Comment: What if `$_SESSION['x']` is not set?

Comment: @b0s3 that was exactly my next question

Comment: What exactly you need if both of these were empty or not set @LouisLoudogTrottier

Comment: in this case, null is great, sorry i added a clarification. =>  i was wondering if we can achieve the same, in a simple way' like in JS even if we had many variables to work with? `$x=($a||$b||$c||$d);`

Comment: Check my updated answer this is what you're going to get using `ternary` operator @LouisLoudogTrottier. Ternary are used for short code of `if..else` if there are **n** number of conditions then you can move to `switch case` instead

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach is to create a function that can accept variables.

```
 public function getFirstValid(&...$params){
    foreach($params as $param){
        if (isset($param)){
            return $param;
        }
    }
    return null;
 }
```

and then to initialize a variable i would do...

```
var $x = getFirstValid($_POST["x"],$_SESSION["y"],$_POST["z");
```

the result will be that the var x will be assign the first variable that is set or is set to null if none of the variables pass are set.

explanation:

function getFirstValid accepts a variable number of variable pointers(&...) and loops through each checking if it is set, the first variable encountered that is set will be returned.

Comment: This is very similar to the function i had in my original question. Function seems to be the way to go. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

PHP 7 solution:
The `??` operator.

```
$x = expr1 ?? expr2
```

- The value of $x is expr1 if expr1 exists, and is not NULL.
- If expr1 does not exist, or is NULL, the value of $x is expr2.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Comment: At the time of posting this question i don't think PHP 7 was a thing. Much has changed since but still didn't know about this new feature and will definitibely try (and maybe adopt) it. .... And welcome to the community,

Answer (score 0):

It would be simple -

```
$x = (!empty($_POST['x']) ? $_POST['x'] :
          (!empty($_SESSION['x']) ? $_SESSION['x'] : null)
     );
```

Comment: what about if we have many variables? we'll need to do something like `$x=(!empty($a)?$a:(!empty($b)?$b:(!empty($c)?$c:(etc...)));` ?